# How to dynamically filter a PXSelect property based on a form field

Tags: dynamic, filter, acumatica

I want to filter related POReceipts if a PONumber is selected. If no PONumber is selected, I want to show all POReceipts.

A POOrder has many POReceipts

In my graph, I have the following

Data Source

```
public PXSelect<MYGRPH> Document;
```

I want the following property to be able to be dynamically filtered based on PO Number....

```
public PXSelect<POReceipt, Where<POReceit.status, Equal<POStatus.open>>> Receipts]
```

How can I dynamically filter 'Receipts' to add the following clause, if a PO number is filled in?

```
Where<POReceipt.orderNbr, Equal<Current<MYGRAPH.orderNbr>>>  ??
```

Is there a way to dynamically add a restrictor?

Comment: you should be able to do it with current like you have it and add an or clause where current myfilterfield is null. So i want values that equal the selected order unless that selected order is null give me all

Answer (score 0):

Make a view on POOrder:

```
PXSelect<POOrder> Document;
```

In the Form add controls for POOrder key fields:

```
<px:PXDropDown CommitChanges="True" ID="edOrderType" runat="server" AllowNull="False" DataField="OrderType" SelectedIndex="2" />
<px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edOrderNbr" runat="server" DataField="OrderNbr" AutoRefresh="True" />
```

When the user selects the POOrder key fields in the form control it sets the current POOrder cache object and you can use that to filter the other view:

```
public PXSelectJoin<POReceipt,
       LeftJoin<POOrderReceipt, On<POReceipt.receiptNbr, Equal<POOrderReceipt.receiptNbr>>>, 
       Where<POOrderReceipt.pOType, Equal<Current<POOrder.orderType>>, 
       And<POOrderReceipt.pONbr, Equal<Current<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>> Receipts;
```

**EDIT:**

> The problem is, that the POOrder field will not always be filled in
>   first.

Add Or clauses as Brendan suggested in the comments:

```
public PXSelectJoin<POReceipt,
       LeftJoin<POOrderReceipt, On<POReceipt.receiptNbr, Equal<POOrderReceipt.receiptNbr>>>,
       Where<Where2<Where<Current<POOrder.orderType>, IsNull,
                    Or<Current<POOrder.orderType>, Equal<POOrderReceipt.pOType>>>,
       And<Where2<Where<Current<POOrderReceipt.pONbr>, IsNull>,
                  Or<Current<POOrderReceipt.pONbr>, Equal<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>>>> Receipts;
```

Comment: The problem is, that the POOrder field will not always be filled in first.